# Есть ли способ добавить несколько языковых пакетов одновременно в TSS Vosk?

Tags: c#, tts, vosk

Я столкнулся с проблемой что TTS Vosk не корректно определяет предложения которые я произношу. В этих предложениях присутствуют слова на английском языке. Как то можно внедрить сразу несколько языков в TTS Voks? Я пробовал оба пакета и легкий и тяжелый. Пишу на C#